# How to generate a PDF?

Tags: c#, pdf

For my Microsoft Surface application I'd like to generate a PDF including some images. How should I start to do that?

EDIT:
I don't want to convert a text or html document, but I want to create a pdf from scratch.

Comment: what do you want to generate PDFs from? other documents (word, excel, etc.), the application UI itself, or build them from scratch in code?

Comment: I'd want to generate them from scratch

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I programmatically create a PDF in my .NET application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177/how-do-i-programmatically-create-a-pdf-in-my-net-application)

Answer (score 6):

[PDFsharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/) is nice, free, relatively easy to use and compatible with WPF

Comment: @mizipzor - they moved the site, I've fixed the link

Answer (score 4):

Two basic options:

1. use a PDF specific library, like iText in @Kent's answer
2. install a PDF printer and use any reporting/printing code.

Option 1) will be the most flexible and efficient way.
Option 2) is interesting when you already have code that prints what you want. It is a bit of a hassle to manage the output-file etc. It's very easy to support XPS as well.

Answer (score 2):

[Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) may be used to create PDF files from scratch and many other purposes.

Please take a look at [samples for various PDF tasks](https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples).

The library has no external dependencies and is written in C#. There are several [different license types](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/licenses/) available.

Disclaimer: I work for Bit Miracle.

Answer (score 1):

For me the easiest way is to use Reporting Services.
http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/reporting.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You should also have a look at Fop/PdfBox for PDF creation/editing.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use one of PDF generation libraries for C#. I tried to use iText , IronPDF and PDFFlow. All of them create PDF documents from scratch.

But [PDFFlow](https://go.pdfflow.io/pdfflow-home) was better for my needs, because it has easy fluent syntax and more functionality (I needed repeating headers, automatic page creation, automatic page numeration and multi-page spread table). They also have examples of business documents here: Examples, I haven't seen that much from other PDF generating libraries. There are also how-to-build articles for each sample, that helped me much.

This is how to create simple PDF file:

```
var DocumentBuilder.New()  
  .AddSection()  
    .AddParagraphToSection("Hello world!") 
    .AddImage("image.png").SetWidth(250) 
  .ToSection() 
    .AddLine(300, Color.Red) 
.ToDocument()  
   .Build("Result.PDF");
```

Hope, this will help you to start.