# Download contents of html text area tag as word or pdf file in c#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am working on a ASP .NET project where the requirement is to download a text area content as a file like .doc, .pdf and .txt.

I know we can download the plain text of text area as .txt using java script but the thing I want to know is,

- How can I achieve the same for .doc and .pdf

is there any java script/jquery way to achieve this if not then what is the right way to do this in native C#.

examples or links would be great.

Comment: textarea will have plain text only, why download as doc or pdf ?

Answer (score 0):

PDF and Word Documents are complex file types.  If you want to generate these files client side, you'll need a javascript library that can generate files in these formats.  I don't think these exist (as this is an uncommon request), but you can google it.

If I would be faced with a problem like this, I would post the value of the textbox back to the server and generate the files on the server.  This SO post discusses how to create a pdf file in C#: [How to generate a PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4545872/1224069)

Once you have created the file server side, you can then send it back to the client.